# Max-pooling with complex masks in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have a matrix `src` with shape `(5, 3)` and a boolean matrix `adj` with shape  `(5, 5)` as follow,

```
src = tensor([[ 0,  1,  2],
              [ 3,  4,  5],
              [ 6,  7,  8],
              [ 9, 10, 11],
              [12, 13, 14]])
```

and

```
adj = tensor([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

We can take each row in `src` as one node embedding, and regard each row in `adj` as the indicator of which nodes are the neighborhood.

My goal is to operate a max-pooling among all neighborhood node embeddings for each node in `src`.
For example, as the neighborhood nodes (including itself) for the 0-th node is `0, 2, 3`, thus we compute a max-pooling on `[0, 1, 2]`, `[6, 7, 8]`, `[ 9, 10, 11]` and lead an updated embedding `[ 9, 10, 11]` to update 0-th node in `src_update`.

A simple solution I wrote is

```
src_update = torch.zeros_like(src)
for index in range(adj.size(0)):
    list_of_non_zero = adj[index].nonzero().view(-1)
    mat_non_zero = torch.index_select(src, 0, list_of_non_zero)
    src_update[index] = torch.sum(mat_non_zero, dim=0)
```

And `src_update` is updated as:

```
tensor([[ 9, 10, 11],
        [ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [12, 13, 14]])
```

Although it works, it runs very slowly and doesn't look elegant!
Any suggestions to improve it for **better efficiency**?

In addition, if both `src` and `adj` are appended with **batches** (`(batch, 5, 3)`, `(batch, 5, 5)`), how to make it works?

Comment: I suggest you look at pytorch scatter library: https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/1.3.0/functions/max.html

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with your code:

```
output = torch.zeros_like(src)
for index in range(adj.size(0)):
  nz = adj[index].nonzero().view(-1)
  output[index] = src.index_select(0, nz).max(0).values
```

The bottleneck is of course the *for loop*. What first comes to mind is to use some kind of scatter function. However, the main issue here is the fact that the number of neighbors can vary from row to row. This means we will be unable to construct a tensor containing the candidate nodes before max pooling.

---

One possible solution is to create a helper tensor similar to `src` where the first node would contain placeholder values (these **should not** get chosen by the max-pooling, *i.e.* we can use `-inf`). We can index this tensor using a tensor containing indices: compared to your method, instead of removing the zeros with `torch.nonzero()`, we will place an index value of *0* (referring to the placeholder row in the first position of *modified-`src`*).

In practice, here how it looks like:

For the helper tensor `src_`, I placed `-1`s as placeholder values.

```
>>> src_ = torch.cat((-torch.ones_like(src[:1]), src))
tensor([[-inf, -inf, -inf],
        [  0.,   1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [  6.,   7.,   8.],
        [  9.,  10.,  11.],
        [ 12.,  13.,  14.]])
```

We can convert the `adj` matrix into a tensor of indices:

```
>>> index = torch.arange(1, adj.size(1) + 1)*adj
tensor([[1, 0, 3, 4, 0],
        [0, 2, 3, 4, 0],
        [1, 2, 0, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3, 0, 5]])
```

For easier indexing we will flatten `index`, index `src_` on the first axis, and reshape right after:

```
>>> indexed = src_[index.flatten(), :].reshape(*adj.shape, 3)
tensor([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
         [-inf, -inf, -inf],
         [  6.,   7.,   8.],
         [  9.,  10.,  11.],
         [-inf, -inf, -inf]],

        ...

        [[-inf, -inf, -inf],
         [-inf, -inf, -inf],
         [  6.,   7.,   8.],
         [-inf, -inf, -inf],
         [ 12.,  13.,  14.]]])
```

Finally you can max-pool:

```
>>> indexed.max(dim=1).values
tensor([[ 9., 10., 11.],
        [ 9., 10., 11.],
        [12., 13., 14.],
        [ 6.,  7.,  8.],
        [12., 13., 14.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ivan gave a pretty smart solution. The key idea is to transform mask to index. I have tested it and wrapped it up to the function below

```
def mask_max_pool(embeddings, mask):
'''
Inputs:
------------------
embeddings: [B, D, E], 
mask: [B, R, D], 0s and 1s, 1 indicates membership

Outputs:
------------------
max pooled embeddings: [B, R, E], the max pooled embeddings according to the membership in mask
max pooled index： [B, R, E], the max pooled index
'''
    B, D, E = embeddings.shape
    _, R, _ = mask.shape
    # extend embedding with placeholder
    embeddings_ = torch.cat([-1e6*torch.ones_like(embeddings[:, :1, :]), embeddings], dim=1)
    # transform mask to index
    index = torch.arange(1, D+1).view(1, 1, -1).repeat(B, R, 1) * mask# [B, R, D]
    # batch indices
    batch_indices = torch.arange(B).view(B, 1, 1).repeat(1, R, D)
    # retrieve embeddings by index
    indexed = embeddings_[batch_indices.flatten(), index.flatten(), :].view(B, R, D, E)# [B, R, D, E]
    # return
    return indexed.max(dim=-2)
```